# Custom search in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-search

I have been working on Implementing `Custom search` in `Android` App-bar. So, I have added following code in `menu_main.xml`

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:hint="Enter Tags"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Now when I am looking at `HomeActivity`. It's look like this:

[image]

It's perfectly fine!. I haven't implemented the backend code for above `SearchView`. Now, I want to add some following features in above `Search bar`

- User can search with tags (Searching with tags means that if there is a space between two words then I will treat them as tags). It's very similar to `Pintreset` app.
- Further I want to get these tags from `Search Bar` and put into `Get` request parameter.

  Screenshot

[image]

## Questions

- For now, forgot about the `Style`. I just want to know How can I achieve this in my `Search Bar`?
- How can I add box on every tag with this cross sign in `Android app bar`?

Any help would be appreciable.

## Edit-1

I am adding `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    if (null != searchView) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.
            return  true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I am getting the submitting text in `onCreateOptionsMenu.onQueryTextSubmit` method. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom search view in order to access to EditText in toolbar (`app:actionViewClass` property in menu layout). After set `TextWathcer` and manage spans inside `afterTextChanged` callback.

I wrote some example with basic background spans implementation. It is main concept and start point in solving your issue.

See example below:

**menu_main.xml:**

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:hint="Enter Tags"
    app:actionViewClass="your.package.CustomSearchView" />
```

**CustomSearchView.java:**

```
public class CustomSearchView extends SearchView {

    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchAutoComplete;

    public CustomSearchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public CustomSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public CustomSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        mSearchAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

        if (mSearchAutoComplete == null) {
            Log.wtf("TEST", "Some Changes in AppCompat????");
            return;
        }
        mSearchAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                mSearchAutoComplete.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                setSpans(s, Color.RED);
                mSearchAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setSpans(Editable s, @ColorInt int backgroundColor) {
        BackgroundColorSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), BackgroundColorSpan.class);

        String[] words;
        if (s.toString().endsWith(" ")) {
            words = (s.toString() + "X").split("\\s");
        } else {
            words = s.toString().split("\\s");
        }
        int completedWordsCount = words.length - 1;
        if (spans.length != completedWordsCount) {
            for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
                s.removeSpan(span);
            }

            int currentIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
                s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(backgroundColor), currentIndex, currentIndex + words[i].length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                currentIndex += words[i].length() + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. This link might be also useful for you in order to set Clickable spans - [Link](https://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/making-gosmsproevernote-like-edittext/).

Comment: Thanks for answering it. Will `mSearchAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);` will be `mSearchAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);` ?

Comment: I am not showing any `AutoCompleteTextView`. User will add some string with spaces. After that I need to take these words and make a query

Comment: @AmitPal Yes, you do not show, but this is how it is implemented inside Android source code. Look here - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/SearchView.java#116.

Comment: @AmitPal If you want you can replace AutoCompleteTextView with EditText. Your control will work exactly the same as EditText until you set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: Ah! I see. BTW I am getting these errors in above code :
http://pastebin.com/z3JCUY3V

Please have a look at it

Comment: @AmitPal Sorry, I did a typo. mSearchAutoComplete should be `private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchAutoComplete`. See edited answer

Comment: and `action_s` will be replaced by ?

Comment: @AmitPal, I don't understand what action_s do you mean?

Comment: I don't have `action_s` in my menu item. Are you referring to `action_search` (Please have a look at menu_main in your answer). If yes, then I am still getting the `could not find symbol variable action_search` where as the `Id` is same in `<item>` . Why is to so? It's not even showing on auto suggestions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93146/discussion-between-alexandr-and-amit-pal).