# How to modify search bar with bitmap in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap

I was reading this awesome [blog](https://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/making-gosmsproevernote-like-edittext/) and  [Contact Bubble EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext) to add bubble in `TextView`. In my situation I do have `Editable` instead of `TextView`. Here is my code:

```
private void setSpans(Editable s, @ColorInt int backgroundColor) {
  BackgroundColorSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), BackgroundColorSpan.class);
  String[] words;
    if (s.toString().endsWith(" ")) {
        words = (s.toString() + "X").split("\\s");
    } else {
        words = s.toString().split("\\s");
    }


    int completedWordsCount = words.length - 1;
    if (spans.length != completedWordsCount) {
        for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
            s.removeSpan(span);
        }

        int currentIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
            s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(backgroundColor), currentIndex, currentIndex + words[i].length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            currentIndex += words[i].length() + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Reference of the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294731/custom-search-in-android)

How can I make this `Editable` field work like above pasted `blog`. Is there any way to add `oval shape` in `s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(backgroundColor), currentIndex, currentIndex + words[i].length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);` instead of `Background Color`?

I am newbie in Android bitmap. How can I achieve it?

Comment: see DynamicDrawableSpan

Comment: @pskink Looking at it