# Disabling edittext searchview after user input

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, searchview, disabled-input

How to disable **EditText searchview** after completion of input on fragment?

Comment: Have you called the method visibility from the class?
"searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);"

Comment: Its work, i want when I hit enter on searchview input text, I want to disable the input text and set the input result in the action bar. If the user wants to re-enter, then the user just press X (clear) icon in the top panel to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `View.OnFocusChangeListener` to your editText and after focus change call `setEnabled(false)`. for eg.

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() { 
@Override 
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
      //let the user input
    } else { 
        //disable you search view

        mEditText.setEnabled(false);


    } 
} 
});
```

P.S. -If you are still facing a problem, please update your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry sir, i want if when I hit enter on searchview input text, I want to disable the input text and set the input result in the action bar. If the user wants to re-enter, then the user just press X (clear) icon in the top panel to the right

Comment: You can see this question it may be useful as per your requirement. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294731/custom-search-in-android)

Comment: Yey, this helps me a lot. Thank you bro!!

Answer (score 0):

If user have to click button after enter text into searchview, you can handle this in event button click method. In your button click method you can write:

```
search.setEnabled(false);
```